# Why is AdMob limiting my ads, despite always using test ads and never clicking on my own ads?

Tags: android, admob

I have an Android app with a single AdMob banner ad, and yesterday I was given a policy violation which limits my ads due to invalid traffic concerns. I am incredibly confused why this is happening because I am extremely careful to use test ad unit IDs when developing, and I never click on my own ads.

Oddly the timing of the violation was suspiciously close to when I was running the app locally on my own physical device with the test ad unit, but to reiterate I am 100% sure I was using the test banner ad unit ID. Is there anything else I should check which I could be missing?

I know this is not very much to go on, but if anyone has the slightest idea of what could be going on here I am willing to try anything at this point. I am finding it nearly impossible to contact AdMob Support, and I would like to avoid switching to a different ad network if possible. I already have mediation set up with FAN and MoPub, but the eCPM and fill rate is far worse for me on both networks.

Comment: hey what is your admob status now? just check if this answer could help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596529/9846650